# Programmatically set size of UIView from Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have placed `UIView` in `UIScrollView` in `Storyboard`. The `UIView` is pinned to the all the sides of the `UIScrollView`. I am trying to set the size of `UIView` programatically because it is needed for scrolling to work properly. How can I programmatically set the width and height of the `UIView`?
Thanks for any help as I am trying to solve the problem already for a week...

Comment: reset frame.
yourView.Frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, yourWidth, yourHeight);
and if even after this it is not changing them may be you have checked autolayout.AND you cannot just change the frame of an object that has autolayout constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change the frame of your view as below:

```
yourView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,calculatedWidth,calculatedHeight);
```

Plus, you'll also need to check for the scroll view's frame so that it enlarges as per your view's width and height.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set new frame to change width, height, x or y for example:

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, newWidth, newHeight);
```